# Can not change or update log events in usage and health data collection service in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, site-usage, monitoring

Run central admin from one of app server where c.a hosts.

- And Monitoring > Configure usage and health data collection> and trying to changing the log events,

When I unselect some events and click ok, i got below message.

> This service instance 'Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage' cannot
>   be provisioned on server 'APP01' because it is mapped to server
>   'WFE02'.

When i run below command

```
GEt-SPUsageApplication | Select -ExpandProperty ServiceInstances
```

I got below results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check:

- from central admin > application management > service application, make sure Usage and Health Data Collection Proxy is started.
- Make sure  “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import” and “Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing” jobs are running as per schedule.
- Make sure Search service is running.
- Make sure Usage Logs properly created.(`typically found C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS\RequestUsage`
- You can also enable Verbose logging and see ifyou see further details in Logs, also check the event log.

Please check this for more details information:
[TROUBLESHOOTING SHAREPOINT 2013 WEB ANALYTICS](http://blog.fpweb.net/troubleshooting-sharepoint-2013-web-analytics/)